# Decoding And Encoding Strings - HardCoded KEY for Symmetric Algorithms

Tags: c#, asp.net, key, encryption-symmetric

i wrote the below class for encoding and decoding string data (Symmetric Algorithm With One Key):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace MyProject.Classes
{
    public static class SymmetricEncryption
    {
        private const string MyKey = "bla bla bla";

        private static string _AlgorithmName;
        public static string AlgorithmName
        {
            get { return _AlgorithmName; }
            set { _AlgorithmName = value; }
        }

        public static string EncryptData(string ClearData)
        {
            // Convert string ClearData to byte array
            byte[] ClearData_byte_Array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearData);

            // Now Create The Algorithm
            SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
            Algorithm.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyKey);

            // Encrypt information
            MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

            // Append IV
            Algorithm.GenerateIV();
            Target.Write(Algorithm.IV, 0, Algorithm.IV.Length);

            // Encrypt Clear Data
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(ClearData_byte_Array, 0, ClearData_byte_Array.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Output
            byte[] Target_byte_Array = Target.ToArray();
            string Target_string = Convert.ToBase64String(Target_byte_Array);
            return Target_string;
        }

        public static string DecryptData(string EncryptedData)
        {
            byte[] EncryptedData_byte_Array = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedData);

            // Now Create The Algorithm
            SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
            Algorithm.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyKey);

            // Decrypt information
            MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

            // Read IV
            int ReadPos = 0;
            byte[] IV = new byte[Algorithm.IV.Length];
            Array.Copy(EncryptedData_byte_Array, IV, IV.Length);
            Algorithm.IV = IV;
            ReadPos += Algorithm.IV.Length;

            // Decrypt Encrypted Data
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(EncryptedData_byte_Array, ReadPos, EncryptedData_byte_Array.Length - ReadPos);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Output
            byte[] Target_byte_Array = Target.ToArray();
            string Target_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Target_byte_Array);
            return Target_string;
        }


    }
}
```

and usage like below :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SymmetricEncryptionUtility.AlgorithmName = "TripleDES";
    Response.Write(SymmetricEncryptionUtility.EncryptData("1234-4567-8910-2345"));
}
```

i have some problem about MyKey -> **how can we have hard coded key for Symmetric Algorithms and use it in the upper class ?**

the upper codes ERROR is like below :

> ```
>     Server Error in '/' Application.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>     Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm. 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> ```
>
> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> ```
>     Exception Details:
> ```
>
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified key is
>   not a valid size for this algorithm.

how can i fix this error ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to securely generate the correct number of bytes for your key based on a `string` password and `byte[]` salt:

```
var helper = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
algorithm.Key = helper.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
```

For more information about `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and how to use it, check out its [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Read the error and look at the documentation for [`TripleDES.Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key.aspx):

> This algorithm supports key lengths from 128 bits to 192 bits in increments of 64 bits.

That means for example

```
private const string MyKey = "bla bla bla blah";
```

would work.

You didn't ask about this, but I'm not sure creating this class as static is a good idea. If you used it from two different places in your code, it could result in unexpected results, because `AlgorithmName` is static.

Also, I don't think it makes sense to have a constant key but variable algorithm, especially since different algorithms require keys of different lengths.

Comment: @LostLord, it's not about the string per se, but about the `byte[]` that you create from it. You're using UTF8 encoding, all the characters are from ASCII, so each one of them is encoded using one byte. And after converting bits into bytes this means you need 16 to 24 characters in increments of 8 characters (i.e. 16 or 24 characters).